# How do I show the value beside an HTML5 range input type?

Tags: html, printing, input

Okay so I am trying to use range for input type

```
Times: <input type="range" name ="times"><br>
```

But I want the value to be printed next to it, how can I do this?

Like

-------*-- 7

*--------- 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

attach to it onChange event 
and in the event handler function you can select the value of the 
  and write it as innerHtml to a span beside the controller

```
<input id="mine" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" step="10" onChange="change();"> <span id="result"></span>

<script>
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var mine = document.getElementById("mine");
function change(){
    result.innerText = mine.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You do a `getElementById` query for both elements *every time* the handler is invoked? Really?!

Comment: That's perfectly normal. You can always set an object, but then you have to look for it each time and make sure it is set, a lot more code just to convey a simple concept.

Comment: it was a speed example to elaborate the idea of course doing such thing in the code would waste resources

Answer (score 0):

```
function showCount(){
    var count = document.getElementById("slider").value;
    console.log("meter position : "+count);
}

<input type="range" value="0" id="slider" step="1" min="0" max="15" onchange="showCount()"/>
```

This will give the count when you will move the slider`enter code here` or put and alert.